# FluentAssertions graph comparison, ExcludingNestedObjects ignored?

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-assertions

I've got a unit/integration test as follows.

```
using (var repository = _factory.Get())
{
    applicationBefore = repository.Applications
        .Include(a => a.AcceptedAgreements)
        .Single(a => a.AggregateId == applicationId);
}

// Perform an operation that deletes an Application and all
// related data and then rebuilds it from the event store.

Repo.Application applicationAfter = null;

using (var repository = _factory.Get())
{
    applicationAfter = repository.Applications
        .Include(a => a.AcceptedAgreements)
        .Single(a => a.AggregateId == applicationId);
}

applicationAfter.AcceptedAgreements.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(applicationBefore.AcceptedAgreements, options => options
    .ExcludingNestedObjects());
```

The `repository` reference is a `DbContext` and `AcceptedAgreements` is a navigation property.

This test fails with the following message.

```
Result Message: 
FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionFailedException : 
Expected item[0].Application.Id to be 1, but found 2.
<more failures where stuff inside Application is different>

With configuration:
- Use declared types and members
- Compare enums by value
- Include all non-private properties
- Include all non-private fields
- Match member by name (or throw)
- Be strict about the order of items in byte arrays
- FluentAssertions.Equivalency.ShouldAllBeEquivalentToHelper+CollectionMemberOrderingRuleDecorator
```

If I modify the assertion as follows:

```
applicationAfter.AcceptedAgreements.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(applicationBefore.AcceptedAgreements, options => options
    .Excluding(o => o.Application));
```

Now the test passes.

Please help me understand why `ExcludingNestedObjects()` doesn't exclude the `Application` property, which is in fact a nested object, and I have to resort to excluding each navigation property individually. The above code is slightly simplified as I actually have multiple navigation properties and have to exclude each of them individually.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @DennisDoomen: Best guess based on our source control is that it was 3.3.0 at the time. We're currently using 3.4.1 and I just tried changing the code back to use `ExcludingNestedObjects()` and it still fails the test but with a slightly different error. Rather than enumerating the differences between the two `Application` objects it just dumps both objects with an "expecting ... but found ..." message, which results in a test failure message that is ~30,000 lines long. If it would help I can send you the failure message but it's too large to post here.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using 3.4.1? It should have been fixed in 3.4.0: https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/commit/2c8a3e108c49e207a7c94d9a7e2079235cd1286f

Comment: Yes, positive. Packages folder, packages.config, assemblies, all show 3.4.1.

Comment: Wait, just to be clear, `ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo` will compare the properties of each item in the source collection of the properties in the target collection. So, the fact that it compares the `Application` property of the first item with the equally named property of the second item is correct. What kind of object is `Application` pointing to?

Comment: [This unit test](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/blob/develop/Tests/FluentAssertions.Shared.Specs/CollectionEquivalencySpecs.cs#L718) should be doing the exact same thing (and passed obviously)